# Derived ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess Returning False in ASP.net MVC Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, claims-based-identity

Sources say that if a child class of `ClaimsAuthorizationManager`'s `CheckAccess` returns false, by framework design, it throws a security exception.

There seems to be no way to catch this error if I want to decorate an ApiController's function with (for example) `[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Operation="Read", Resource="Something")]`.

I already created a sample AuthorizationManager, deriving ClaimsAuthorizationManager, and registered it in web.config. This configuration part works.

```
public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
     public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
     {
          return false; // just to show that it will throw the security exception
     }     
}
```

So, I set up authorization to fail no matter what, but I want to return a 401 response back to the user instead of that "invasive" 500 (Security exception returned as Internal Server Error).

Nobody seems to have an answer for this anywhere, and it seems like we'll just settle for the 500 to communicate unauthorized access to clients.

Comment: Did you reach a better solution? It feels wrong to return a 500 when it's obviously meant to be a 401. Thinking that I would be better off implementing a custom AuthenticationFilter because I can easily return a 401 from one of those.

Comment: related or same question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774130/return-401-when-claimsauthorizationmanager-checkaccess-returns-false)

Answer (score 0):

This is only an idea but I believe you could also set a flag in the Items container and then in the Application_EndRequest you could check if these two conditions occur:

- response status code is 500
- the flag is set

In such case you could just change the status code to 401.