# Return 401 when ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess returns false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, claims-based-identity

I'm using a custom `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` to implement authorization in a Web API 2 project

To do that, one overrides the `CheckAccess()` method to decide if the current principal should be allowed access, and return the corresponding boolean. The problem is that returning `false` causes an `Exception` to be thrown, which ends up as a `500 Internal Server Error`, while the desired outcome is a `401 Unauthorized` (or maybe a `403 Forbidden`?).

Is there a way to override the outcome of a failed claims verification so that it returns a "proper" HTTP response and not a catch-all 500?

Comment: Can you add to the authorization context.ErrorResult before returning false?

Comment: Or Instead of returning false, throw a UserNotAuthorizedException

Comment: The context is not System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext but [System.Security.Claims.AuthorizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.authorizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) which has no access to any of that. That's why I'm considering using the filter, where MVC's AuthorizationContext would allow me to do what you're saying.
Throwing my own exception would be similar to the current behaviour, as in I'd have to handle that exception somewhere further up.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing authorization with authentication?  How are you authenticating the user to use the Api technology?  During authentication you can handle your claims business which can return what ever status code you like.

Comment: I'm authenticating using an AuthenticationFilter to perform authentication and set the principal, as per [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters). The authorization only happens at a later stage, and I'm trying to use [ClaimsPrincipalPermission](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.claimsprincipalpermission%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes to implement that side of things.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this two articles:

[Article 1](http://forums.asp.net/t/2043922.aspx?Catch+Security+Exception+with+attribute+Web+Api+)

[Article 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

You can implement your own `ExceptionFilterAttribute`, something like this

```
public class SecurityExceptionFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception is System.Security.SecurityException)
        {
            actionExecutedContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return;
        }

        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

and then in `Global.asax` file just add this filter to `HttpConfiguration`:

```
config.Filters.Add(new SecurityExceptionFilterAttribute());
```